# Mixed $L^p \ell^q$ -norm Minkowski type inequality?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to find whether it is true that for functions $\{ f(x,k)\}$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, and 
$x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, that lie in $L^q_x$ and $\ell_k^p$ simultaneously that 
\begin{align*} || f ||_{L^q_x \ell_k^p} \leq || f ||_{\ell_k^p L^q_x} \end{align*}
where
\begin{align*} || f ||_{L^q_x \ell_k^p} := 
\left( \int \left( \sum_k |f(x,k)|^p \right)^{q/p} dx \right)^{1/q} \end{align*}

thanks!

Comment: I guess your $\ell^p L^q$ norm is given by $$ \Big( \sum_{k} \| f(\cdot, k) \|_q^p \Big)^\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: Hint: That is true iff $q \geq p$.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez  do you have a reference for this? I need to use the result and couldn't find it in the literature. If you do not I'll try and prove it but it sounds like you've seen this result?

Comment: You can mix interpolation with the case $p = q = 2$ and the inequality in the case $q = \infty$ and $p = 1$, which is immediate.

Comment: thanks for the comment!